# Remove extra window title bar

Tags: window, titlebar, 21.10

After an update from Ubuntu 21.04 to 21.10, I now have an extra bar on top of some windows. The bar is completely blank. So far, I noticed it in Nautilus. See the extra space above the buttons in this screenshot:

[image]

How can I remove this bar?

Comment: 20.04 LTS is supported until 2025. 20.10 being an interim release had only 9 months and already expired. Your solutions now are (1) Reinstall 20.04 or (2) install the current 21.10 that can easily be upgraded next year to 22.04, the upcoming LTS with again 5 years of support. There's no point in going from 20.10 > 21.04 > 21.10. Do your backups and install fresh regardless of your choice.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was on 21.04, then upgraded to 21.10.